# Afraid to disagree with a downvote?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have a question that was downvoted without giving a reason. There's been a little activity and it seems to me like a legitimate question, but nobody has upvoted it (or if they have, somebody else has also downvoted it).

Is there a reason this was d/v'd? or are people just generally afraid to disagree with a downvote? The -1 score bothers me because it means people won't look at the problem.

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27713/assign-undirected-edges-in-a-mixed-graph-to-make-graph-cyclic-acyclic

Comment: I don't think people are afraid to disagree with down votes. If the question has not got up-voted maybe it is because people haven't found it interesting/well-written/shown enough effort/... For previous discussion about down-voting without commenting see [this meta discussion](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1395/).